# How can a .NET date be converted to NSTimeInterval?

Tags: c#, iphone, .net, ios, cocoa

We have .NET code (C#) that writes to a SQLite database, which is then read by an iOS (iPhone) app with objective-c.

The date format used in SQLite is NSTimeInterval (to NSDate with dateWithIntervalSince1970) because it's efficient on the iPhone.

**How can .NET DateTime be converted to NSTimeInterval so that when it is extracted with dateWithIntervalSince1970 the date is correct?**

Notes:
1)  I tried to search on how NSTimeInterval works fundamentally but only find this opaque documentation:
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_DataTypes/Reference/reference.html

2)  Although C# code would be ideal **I'd be happy with pseudo-code that goes from 3 ints (year/month/day) to a double.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you mean `NSTimeInterval`. `NSTimeInterval` represents a span of time, in seconds, so its logical equivalent in .NET is `System.TimeSpan` rather than `System.DateTime`. But, if you specify it as the span of time *since `January 1, 1970 00:00:00 GMT`*, which is what you get with `-timeIntervalSince1970`, then the conversion between it and `System.DateTime` becomes possible.

To convert between `System.DateTime` and a POSIX timestamp (which is what `NSTimeInterval` is in this situation, plus subsecond precision), you probably want something like this:

```
DateTime unixEpoch = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
DateTime dt = ...;
double intervalSince1970 = (dt - unixEpoch).TotalSeconds;
```

To go the other way:

```
DateTime unixEpoch = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
double intervalSince1970 = ...;
DateTime dt = unixEpoch + TimeSpan.FromSeconds(intervalSince1970);
```

Comment: Yes I did mean from .NET Date to NSInterval, and your answer works.  I just made it an extension method that takes as input DateTime and returns a double referenced to 1970.  Thanks -

Comment: public static double ToNSIntervalSince1970(this DateTime dt)
{
    DateTime unixEpoch = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
    double intervalSince1970 = (dt - unixEpoch).TotalSeconds;
    return intervalSince1970;
}

Comment: `NSTimeInterval`, not `NSInterval`.

Comment: Now I see said the blind man :).  Question updated to refer to NSTimeInterval.  Thanks Jonathan.

Answer (score 0):

This is what we have in one of our utils hope it helps.

```
private static double GetUnixEpoch(this DateTime dateTime)
{
    var unixTime = dateTime.ToUniversalTime() - 
        new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);

    return unixTime.TotalSeconds;
}

var epochTime = DateTime.Now.GetUnixEpoch();
```

And if you want to get future date it also works

30 Minutes into the future

```
var unixTime2 = (DateTime.Now + new TimeSpan(0, 30, 0)).GetUnixEpoch();
```